# UITabbar overlaps UINavigation Controller view

Tags: ios, iphone

I have a UITabBarController with 3 UINavigationControllers.

```
uITabBarController.viewControllers = [uINavigationController_1, uINavigationController_2, uINavigationController_3]
```

Within each UINavigationController:

```
self.setViewControllers([self.someTableViewController], animated: false)
```

In someTableViewController:
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(viewController, animated: true)

The UITabbar overlaps the Views in the UINavigationController?

[image]

I have tried to use constraints in code, the following is in the navigationController:

```
override func updateViewConstraints() {
    self.view.bottomAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(self.tabBarController?.view.topAnchor).active = true
    super.updateViewConstraints()
}
```

Comment: I don't think it's very clear what you're asking, could you elaborate at all?

Comment: Thanks, hope the update makes it more clear.

Answer (score 0):

In Interface Builder, select the UINavigationController in question, click the Attribute Inspector, and deselect "Extend Edges: Under Bottom Bars".